# Yet another UnauthorizedAccessException with WMI

Tags: c#, wmi, remote-access

I am trying to run application remotely on WinXP. Here is the code.

```
void RemoteExecute(string userName,
                            string password,
                            string path,
                            object[] commandLine)
    {
        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();

        options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Default;
        options.Username = userName;
        options.Password = password;
        options.Authority = null;
        options.EnablePrivileges = true;

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(path, options);
        scope.Connect();

        using (ManagementClass process = new ManagementClass("Win32_Process"))
        {
            process.Scope = scope;
            process.InvokeMethod("Create", commandLine);
        }
    }

...
object[] commandLine = { "cmd.exe", null, null, 0 };
        RemoteExecute("acid",
                    "123",
                    @"\\192.168.142.128\Root\CIMV2",
                    commandLine);
```

Then I got exception on `scope.Connect()`: `Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`. Googling about this lead me to tweak Security settings on target machine. Here is what I have done.

1. Disabled firewalls on both source and target boxes
2. DCOMCNFG => Component Services => My Computer => Properties => COM Security => Access Permissions/Lunch and Activation Permissions => Edit Limits/Edit Default => add account/put all possible allow checkmarks.
3. WMI Control => Properties => Security ROOT and CIMV2 => Security => Added new account/put checkmark on Allow everywhere.
4. Tried with account `administrator`. No empty passwords.

What else should I do to avoid exception?

Comment: Disabling Simple File Sharing helped.